# Using iText to create PDF, special characters display properly when executed from command line don't display from app

Tags: java, php, apache, .htaccess, pdf

I have a PDF that is being generated using iText 5 with Java. Recently, I discovered that special characters (° ≥ ≤ etc..) were not displaying. I have embedded a unicode .ttf file and have been able to generate a PDF with the characters necessary if executing the .jar logged in as myself from the command line. When executing the .jar from a php file (using shell_exec(), exec(), and system()) the PDF is created and all of the content is there, except the special characters have been replaced with ? symbols.

I have a feeling that the issue is stemming from apache being logged in as the user. To verify that it was not a php issue, I also started an interactive php session, logged in as myself, and used the exact command that is being executed by the web application (shell_exec(), exec(), and system()) and the characters display correctly.

Additionally, I have checked httpd.conf to determine if the defaultCharSet was UTF-8 and found the AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 was present. I have also created a .htaccess file setting UTF-8 as the default charset.

Any ideas as to what is going on? I feel it has to be user/apache related, but have hit a wall.

UPDATE:
I have a button click event that triggers the php command:

$output = shell_exec("java -jar /data/eng/java/pdf-generator.jar $arg1 $arg2");

Everything else happens internally from the pdf-generator.jar program where it then make a call to the server which then returns an xml string. I have validated the xml and know that it is not causing the issue. Additionally I have written another test script that uses the php function:

echo mb_detect_encoding($response); which returns the string UTF-8 only so I know the string is encoded in UTF-8.

The PDF always updates regardless of the method of executing the jar, the only difference is the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem. Adding these three lines forced UTF-8 encoding.

```
        $locale='en_US.UTF-8';
        setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
        putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
        $output = shell_exec("java -jar /data/eng/java/pdf-generator.jar $arg1 $arg2");
```